# lualatex MWE not working

Tags: luatex

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}     
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

test

\end{document}
```

creates

```
MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-2016-04-21.lua:353: attempt to call global 'getsubtype' (a nil value)

\endsa@boxit ... dvarwidth \color@endgroup \egroup

1.9 \end{document}

?
```

Any ideas what this could be? I cannot imagein that I am wrong typsetting this example?

Comment: The new luaotfload version (2.7) imho doesn't work with the luatex in miktex. So you need either get an older luaotfload (https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/releases) or try out miktex next: http://www.miktex.org/announcement/miktex-next-5900 (you will perhaps also have to update to luaotfload 2.7-fix-1, I don't know if it is already in miktex).

Comment: Your Luatex is too old, the ``getsubtype`` API has been around since version 0.85 whereas Luaotfload requires 0.95.

Comment: Please provide a answer, so I can accept it. lua 0.8 is compatible with luafloat 2.5

Comment: I hit this page while searching for a solution where luaotfload claims that lualatex 1.0.0 is too old for it. I just upgraded MikTeX and learned that I have to install the recent version of luaotfload manually. See https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/387#issuecomment-258553623

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try loading the `luatex85` package as well:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}     
\usepackage{fontspec,luatex85}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

This works with MacTeX2016 / LuaTeX 0.95.0 / luaotfload 2016/04/21 v2.7. Without the `luatex85` package, the MWE won't compile on this system.

Comment: I have executed the idea of ulrike fischer and reverted to the old version which is now working. If I use your code now, this code wont work but removing luatex85 will make it compileable. Strange...

Comment: @PeterEbelsberger - `luatex85` should definitely only be used with versions of luatex more recent than 0.80. If you have TeXLive2015, you mostly likely have luatex 0.80 and thus shouldn't have to load `luatex85`.

Comment: I have so many answers and it seems to me, that all are very helpful. I do not know which one I should accept as answer. I have reverted to old versions like Ulrike suggested....I will accept your answer, but as untested. Because I won't update now...

Answer (score 1):

When I was trying to solve this same problem I found some information that (as an inexperienced package user) was a little harder to decipher.

I started out by trying to use the `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` as described here [After MiKTeX update when using LuaLaTeX: Package pgf Error: Driver file ``pgfsys-luatex.def'' not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309140/after-miktex-update-when-using-lualatex-package-pgf-error-driver-file-pgfsys) but I then opted to try out the experimental miktex packages (enabled with the checkbox on the main screen of Update (Admin) for MikTeX as described and illustrated:  http://miktex.org/kb/miktex-next).  Then in order to ensure everything was successfully *registered(?)* I went to Settings (Admin) for MikTeX and on the "General" tab, I clicked `RefreshFNDB`.  Then my luatex compiler started working again.

Of course this is a MikTeX oriented procedure that worked for me, but I will update the answer if and when I get this working on my linux machine as well.

Comment: Please see the comment in the answer above.