# After MiKTeX update when using LuaLaTeX: Package pgf Error: Driver file ``pgfsys-luatex.def'' not found

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, luatex, miktex, external-files

I just updated my MiKTeX instance to the latest packages and am using the LuaLaTeX compiler. Whenever a document relies on `pgf` I get the following error:

```
! Package pgf Error: Driver file ``pgfsys-luatex.def'' not found..
```

I found this Bug report, https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/384/, where someone provides the missing file (he simply renamed another driver and did little changes apparently), but this really doesn't solve my problems. The missing file error goes away with this driver, but for example setting `aspectratio=169` as a `beamer` option is fully ignored while it worked perfectly fine with LuaLaTeX before the MiKTeX update.

A minimal example would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}
Compile me with lualatex.exe
\end{document}
```

With the driver from the linked bug report and the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\begin{document}
Foo
\end{document}
```

I only get the default Aspect Ratio of 4:3. Before the MiKTeX update I correctly got 16:9, even with LuaLaTeX.

I tried purging and reinstalling MiKTeX. It did not help.

How can I compile `pgf`-based documents with LuaLaTeX correctly again?

Comment: It is quite unclear what problem you have -- your example compiles fine if I add the missing driver. But the standard answer to all sort of luatex problems is currently "add \RequirePackage{luatex85}" (at best before \documentclass).

Comment: note the new luatex is more or less completely incompatible with pdftex and all previous versions of luatex, that's why it has a version number less than 1 and says beta in its startup banner, interfaces are not fixed and can and do change. a lot of peopel have updated a lot of packages to hide most of the issues but breakage is expected as the new version rolls out.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I updated the question with a MWE when using the driver from the linked bug report and an explanation of the according behavior. I also tried re-installing MiKTeX.

Comment: As I already wrote: try to add \RequirePackage{luatex85} before \documentclass.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Hi. I have the same problem as Foo Bar: after updating/synchronizing MiKTeX 2.9 (in order to fix some issues with `biber`), I get the error message `! Package inputenc Error: inputenc is not designed for xetex or luatex.`. I added `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` before `\documentclass` (so at the very beginning of my document), but it did not change anything. Any idea ? (I use LuaLaTeX with TeXworks)

Comment: @Nicolas: You don't have the same problem as FooBar.  inputenc isn't mentioned anywhere. So don't highjack this thread but make a new question with a correct example and better error description.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am sorry, I have not pasted the correct error: my error is indeed `! Package pgf Error: Driver file ``pgfsys-luatex.def'' not found..`.

Comment: @Nicolas: Get the missing driver from here https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/384/

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for the link. I have saved the file at /tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer, but LuaLaTeX still does not see it; must I synchronize/update MiKTeX ?

Comment: Use a local texmf tree not the main tree http://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/localadditions.html and don't forget to update the fndb -- or put the files in the folder of your document.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I've pasted the `pgfsys-luatex.def` in the folder of my document, and it perfectly works now! I do thank you for your help and your patience!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As an alternative to `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` I opted to try out the experimental miktex packages (enabled with the checkbox on the main screen of Update (Admin) for MikTeX as described and illustrated: http://miktex.org/kb/miktex-next). Then in order to ensure everything was successfully *registered(?)* I went to Settings (Admin) for MikTeX and on the "General" tab, I clicked RefreshFNDB.

Despite using the new experimental package of LuaTeX 0.95 I still had to copy the contents of 
https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/_discuss/thread/44f8dcf2/9dc8/attachment/pgfsys-luatex.def to my texmf structure (I placed it in a secondary structure in `texmf\tex` and re-scanned the roots from Settings (Admin) for MikTeX on the "Roots" tab.