# Starting Tikz/pgf in LuaLatex: Package pgf Error: Driver file "pgfsys-luatex.def" not found

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex

I'm starting to migrate from pdflatex to LuaLatex and with that to using Tikz and the memoir classs. In the case of Tikz I'm following the standard user manual (Manual for Version 2.10-CVS by Till Tantau, 2012) and I'm using the current versions of MikTex (2.9) and tex maker (2.5) on my old windows 7.

This is my first compiled example on both pdflatex and lualatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}

\begin{document}
           \begin{tikzpicture}
               \draw (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
               \draw (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If I run this code on pdflatex then I get the plane of the x and y axes. But, if I run the same code on lualatex I get the message: Package pgf Error: Driver file "pgfsys-luatex.def" not found.

Aside: this question has already been asked before, but besides the fact that it doesn't solved my problem it was asked 5 years ago and I think someone else might be facing the same issue (look [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309140/after-miktex-update-when-using-lualatex-package-pgf-error-driver-file-pgfsys)).

How can I fix it?

Comment: Get the missing driver from here https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/384/, and load \usepackage{luatex85} (as early as possible).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes. That's solved the problem!! thank you.  I think you should elaborate a little more as an answer and why this happens and also where I should put this file or if there's any problem in case of updating the files to newer versions, etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in the comments.