# MiKTeX/TeXworks and LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, miktex, luaotfload

I'm trying to compile a document with the LuaLaTeX engine, since LuaLaTeX is the only one that allows to use all fonts in my computer. But when I'm going to compile the document, I get this error message

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.0 (MiKTeX 2.9.6100)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./formulario.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/size10.clo"))
("C:/Users/Marco/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/microtype/microtyp
e.sty" ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty")
("C:/Users/Marco/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/microtype/microtyp
e-luatex.def" ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.st
y"
("C:/Users/Marco/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctabl
estack.sty")) ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload.st
y"
        FATAL ERROR
        Luaotfload requires a Luatex version >= 0.95.0.
        Please update your TeX distribution!

...les/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-main.lua:36: version check f
ailed
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'error'
        ...les/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-main.lua:36: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
l.49 }

?
```

Sounds like I should update the LuaTeX version: if so, how can I update this?

MiKTeX 2.9.6161
TeXWorks 0.61

Comment: You need a prerelease of luaotfload https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/387

Comment: I extract files to c:\luaotfload. Now, how can I add c:\luaotfload to miktex roots?

Comment: Use the miktex settings dialog.

Comment: Following http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312263/starting-tikz-pgf-in-lualatex-package-pgf-error-driver-file-pgfsys-luatex-def
I get pgfsys-luatex.def file. Now, in which directory should be moved this file?

Comment: xelatex will also be able to use all your system fonts.