# Troubles switching from pdflatex to lualatex

Tags: errors, luatex, fontspec

I am having a really weird Problem, and after 4 hours of googling and trying and failing I hope somebody can help me:

Background Information: I am using texstudio and miktex, my documents are coded in UTF-8

In my document I am using tikz for drawing some trees. Since I am using tikz I was forced to switch from pdflatex to lualatex. Since then all my german umlauts (ÄÖÜ) and the sharp s (?) do not work anymore.

From what I've read in the net, the easiest way to make them working again, is to add `\usepackage{fontspec}` to my preamble and removing

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

So this is what I did. But then I'm getting a lot of errors like the following:

> Font \EU2/lmr/m/n/10=file:lmroman10-regular:script=latn;+trep;+tlig;
>   at 10pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad.
>   \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont
>
> Font \EU2/lmr/m/n/12=file:lmroman12-regular:script=latn;+trep;+tlig;
>   at 12pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad. \normalsize
>
> Font \EU2/lmr/m/n/8=file:lmroman8-regular:script=latn;+trep;+tlig; at
>   8pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad. \begin{tabular}

Okay... Google told me that it seems that i need to add the package lmodern so I added it: `\usepackage{lmodern}`. 
hm... didn't work. Still I am getting the same errors...

Okay, I tried to start a clean document, just to check if the same would happen:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
    TEST: Ä
\end{document}
```

And Yes. The Results are the same:
[image]

So... this is what I tried the last 4 hours and slowly I am getting a little frustrated. I have no Idea \dots

But I hope you can help ;)

Comment: Works here with TeXLive 2016. Is your MikTeX up to date? And is latin modern installed?

Comment: you are missing the opentype fonts that luatex uses

Comment: @MartinSchröder The MiKTeX Package Manager shows the lm (latin modern) package as installed on 17.01.2017.

I installed Miktex about a week ago, so it is pretty up to date, but the updater is just running. May the force be with me.

Comment: You probable either need the luaotfload-release version (see https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/387), or should run a miktex update to get the newest latex format (perhaps you will have to recreate the lualatex format in miktex settings after the update). The log-file should then say LaTeX2e <2017/01/01>)

Comment: Side remark: Don't rely too much on the "Fehler und Warnungen"-Tab. It has a tendency not to show the whole story. Better look in the log-file.#

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I just ran the miktex updater and it updated itself and a whole bunch of packages. I then recreated the lualatex formats in the settings. But the errors still remain:

My Log file posts the following:
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.0 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit)  (format=lualatex 2017.1.23)  24 JAN 2017 17:29

LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3

So it still seems to be an old version (you mentioned 2017/01/01). How would I update this?

Comment: You probably have a user format. Run the updater also as user, and recreate the format with the user version of miktex settings. Make sure that the lualatex is not excluded in the tab "formats"

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I LOVE YOU! This did the trick :D The "normal" updater didn't find any more updates, but I had to recreate the lualatex formats with the user version of the settings. You have no idea how glad I am right now :)

Comment: Why did you have to switch to lulatex from pdflatex to use tikz?

Comment: @HerbSchulz As far as I know, tikz requieres lualatex. At least i wasn't able to use tikz without

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to outdated software, solved with an update of MiKTeX

Comment: Thats up to the administrative steff. But I would't. A topic like this would have saved me the whole afternoon. Google brought a lot of topics by people describing the same issue as I had without an answer. The only answer was to load lmodern, which didn't work. And how should i know that miktex was outdated? I downloaded and installed it just a week ago ;) So this error was quit awkward in my opinion

Comment: @L0g333 : tikz works fine under pdflatex and even under latex

Comment: Well there are quite number of topic like this here - that's why I knew your problem. But you didn't found them because you never looked in the log-file which would have shown you the real error. E.g http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343172/miktex-texworks-and-lualatex. Beside this: two days ago an update wouldn't have helped, you would have to install the prerelease of luaotfload. You can thank @DavidCarlisle and the latex team that this isn't no longer needed with the new latex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to my question is very simple and a little bit silly...

My MikTex was just not up-to-date, despite the fact that the current version was downloaded and installed just a few days ago. So if somebody else is running into this problem some day. Here is what you should do:

1. Run the `MikTex Updater (Admin)` and Update Miktex itself
2. Run the `MikTex Updater (Admin)` again and update all packages (repeat this until the updater tells you that every package is up to date)
3. Run the `MikTex Updater` (without Admin) and repeat steps 1&2
4. Run the `MikTex Settings (Admin)` and recreate the formats
5. Run the `MikTex Settings` (without Admin) and recreate the formats

Thats it. It should work now.