# ! LaTeX Error: File `luatex.def' not found

Tags: pdf, luatex, pandoc, scripts, bash

I've tried to make a bash script that uses pandoc in conjunction with LaTeX to convert my university notes from markdown to PDF. I initially copied the idea and script from someone of which I've edited the script and forked the project, the script I'm having the error with can be found here: https://github.com/alifhughes/notes/blob/master/compile_notes.sh

I'm really new to pandoc, LaTeX and everything that comes with it so I feel i might have left something out during installation of all these components. Currently I've installed: BasicTex, pandoc, ack (used in the script), Ghostscript and luatex.

When I run the script in my shell I get the following error:
[image: padoc/latex-error-message]

My first thought was to install luatex, which i've done, as it was missing some .def file from that, but it hasn't solved the problem. I think this is similar to this problem also posted on the tex stackoverflow: [After MiKTeX update when using LuaLaTeX: Package pgf Error: Driver file ``pgfsys-luatex.def'' not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309140/after-miktex-update-when-using-lualatex-package-pgf-error-driver-file-pgfsys)

But if I'm 100% honest a lot of that is completely Alien to me and doesn't make much sense.

Does anyone have a possible idea of what could be wrong??
Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! There was a reorganisation of the graphics definition files recently, and they're now in the `graphics-def` package. You should update your installation, and possibly ask to install graphics-def.

Comment: Thanks for welcoming me and replying so quick! Is this the right package? https://github.com/latex3/graphics-def or am I completely wrong? If so how do I go about installing that? Im on OSX if that helps.. sorry for the nooby questions, as I said, I'm very new to this all!

Comment: I think what you mention is the development version. you probably should download [this one](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphics-def), but preferably, you should install it via `TeX Live Utility`, a MacOSX interface to TeX Live Package manager. B.t.w., is it TeX Live 2016 you have?

Comment: That tool is brilliant thank you, i've installed the necessary packages (few others that came up that i also installed) but now coming up with a slightly different error.. `fontspec error: "font-not-found" The font "TeX Gyre Pagella" cannot be found.` Seems to be progress but do you think you could point me in the right direction for solving this as well please? I believe I'm only using BasicTex: https://tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html does that seem correct?

Comment: I don't work on a Mac, so I can't be sure, but try to see if TeX Live Utility can install the whole `tex-gyre` (and probably `tex-gyre-math`. I don't think it's possible to install the individual fonts.

Comment: No you are correct, I've installed those packages and it has moved and the whole pdf creation seems to be passing the pandoc stage but failing later on in my script (not Tex related). I appreciate all your help, really thank you! If you're any good at scripting, I'm getting this error: `Error: /undefinedfilename in (*/*.pdf)` from line 85 of my script: https://github.com/alifhughes/notes/blob/master/compile_notes.sh
This is one of my first attempts at scripting and i've mainly got the contents of the script from a forked repo, learning as i go

Comment: Unfortunately I don't much about scripting. Probably someone else on this site can help.

Comment: You will save yourself a great deal of frustration if you install MacTeX rather than BasicTeX. Unless you are on a device with serious space limitations, installing MacTeX should be a no brainer. If you do have serious constraints on the device, is there another machine you could use TeX on? Even if you know what you're doing, it will be frustrating with just BasicTeX. But in the beginning, it will be much worse.

Comment: What does `*/*.pdf` refer to? Diagnose by making the script more verbose: remove options which suppress output or send it to `/dev/null`. Add `set -x`. In any case, you don't want to `exit 0` at the end like that. You want to `exit 1` if the process doesn't succeed. Why do you `unset` variables in the loops? What do you think you are releasing them *for* exactly? This is entirely pointless as far as I can see. `IFS=$'\n'` looks very odd - are you sure about this?