# Debug infinite loop in text file and other stuff

Tags: packages

I have some old code that I am trying to revive. I worked fine before but now it does not, but the code has not changed(so it is due to the changed configuration of the software). There is no real error messages that make sense.

The problem is that there seems to be a package or packages that are interfering because when I remove them the tex code compiles but, of course, lots of errors.

I have gotten some of the code to work by removing the code that depended on the packages. (if the only line is the usepackage statement, it still crashes, meaning it is the package)

The packages are

xparse
atbegshi
xfrac
mdframed(a lot of my code depends on this)

```
Package: xpatch 2012/10/02 v0.3 Extending etoolbox patching commands
.................................................
)
Runaway argument?
\q_stop \exp_args:NNo \group_end: \iow_log:n \l__iow_wrap_tl \iow_log:n \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \__iow_wrap_loop:w.
```

After removing some stuff the infinite loop goes away(I think it is mainly mdframed and xparse).

It seems to be some issue with some stale packages, any ideas where to look or what I can do to try and figure it out?

```
%\tracingall
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}\batchmode

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{silence}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=1in,a4paper]{geometry} % a5paper for electronic reading
\usepackage{luatex, graphicx}
\usepackage[space]{grffile}
\usepackage{tikz, pgffor}
\usepackage{pdfcolmk}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{flafter}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
%\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
%\usepackage{xpatch}
%\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{movie15}
%\usepackage{xfrac}






















\scrollmode


%\batchmode
\begin{document}\scrollmode%\chapendfootnote





\batchmode\end{document}
```

Using miktex 2.9. It could be my install but this should work(again, it used to)

Comment: Very vague. We would need more information to make this issue of yours go away.

Comment: Try to add a mwe!

Comment: The code is far too complex to add anything that would make sense. Sorry. I already gave quite a bit of info about it being specific packages. I included an MWE that stalls and basically includes no code except for loading packages

Comment: And does it 'stall' with the same error you want help with? Also: why are you using `\batchmode` if you are trying to *find* the source of the error? Same goes for the `silence` package. (And, off-topic, but the 'sorry' comment seems a little odd. Are you saying 'Sorry, I'm not willing to try to help the people who want to help me any further than what I've already done?' Given the fact that the code you've provided includes two efforts to suppress console or `.log` output, at best, this seems to be a warning to others to *not* try to help....)

Comment: What is this `luatex` package from this line: `\usepackage{luatex, graphicx}`? Is it supposed to be `ifluatex`? (If I comment out that line, and run your file, even with the other packages uncommented, this compiles fine for me except for the fact that there's no content to typeset.)

Comment: @jon, please don't help. Please take your attitude somewhere else, I don't have time for your assumptions and derogatory remarks. If you don't want to help, or are upset at life, fine... but don't make it my problem.

Comment: I did solve the problem with respect to the file that is posted. (Either with or without `\batchmode` enabled, I can load *all* the packages in the above file.) But this may not solve your real problem, which is why it is up to you provide a meaningful MWE (which can take a frustrating amount of time and effort --- that's just how it is). I was not trying to give attitude, I was simply suggesting that your tone could be more encouraging.

Comment: @jon I said that this example does not compile and gives an infinite loop, batchmode or not... if you comment out the packages you get a MWE. I cannot give you 100+ files. Sorry, not going to happen. If you don't like it too bad. You wouldn't even look at them and it would be of no importance because they have nothing to do with the problem, if they did, then the above would compile just fine.  If it compiles for you and not for me then it means it is on my end and you could be more helpful by giving your system that works rather than trying to pick apart what I have posted trying to be an ass

Comment: @jon it is quite obvious that if I supplied a valid file that compiles with a line commented out and does not compile wih the line not commented out then that line has something to do with the problem, regardless of what I actually built off that file. Asking for more code simply demonstrates that you don't know what is going on. It is obviously a package issue and anyone with enough experience can see that. It's simple "arithmetic problem", no need to complicate it in to something it is not.

Comment: You have misunderstood my comments. I am **not** asking for more packages; and I am trying to help (in two ways: by providing a solution to the problem and by suggesting a better way to ask for help -- namely, and mainly, by suggesting that this question would be better with a true MWE).  And, for what it's worth, I did not downvote this question.

Comment: @jon Then you are going to have to describe what a "true MWE" is because I gave an example that was both nearly minimal(virtually all unnecessary things were removed) and working(as it compiles). I also did better in that I showed what did not compile So I also gave where the problem is. While batchmode and other stuff(left over from when the code worked fine) might hinder error messages, it has nothing to do with infinite loops(does it?!?!). Hence it is irrelevant. The fact that the code above essentially causes lualatex to crash/lock up is enough as infinite loops don't show error messages.

Comment: @AbstractDissonance Your example is not minimal (many package) not complete (`\begin{document}\scrollmode \par
\batchmode\end{document}` is just nothing, whatever preamble you use)

Comment: @touhami Sorry, I do not understand your English.

Comment: He is pointing out that you are not typesetting anything in your non-minimal code.

Comment: Your example and Jons compiles fine on my miktex. Without a complete log-file I can't tell you what is different on your system.

Comment: An MWE does not include anything that is unneeded to recreate the problem. Thus if a file produces error X and has loaded `multicol` and you can reproduce the same error with the same file even when you don't load `multicol`, then `multicol` should not be included in the MWE. Your file contains dozens of files that are unlikely to be the culprit, but the crux is that, in many cases, only you can be certain that `multicol` is or is not related to the problem.

Comment: The problem with `\scrollmode` and `\batchmode` is that TeX tries to fix the problems it encounters, so it clearly not helpful if you and not TeX is trying to locate and fix the problems.

Comment: I tried the example file with TeX Live 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015 and 2016; I get errors only with TL 2015 (because the `luatex` package hadn't been updated, but no infinite loop). Of course I removed the `\batchmode` and `\scrollmode` commands that have nothing to do with error location (but if I leave them in, there's no difference). I also uncommented the calls for `mdframed`, `xpatch`, `atbegshi` and `xfrac`, getting no error either (`movie15` is obsolete, so I left it out). Voting to close as “unclear what you're asking”; it the question is improved, I'll be happy to vote for reopening.

Comment: So, I removed miktex and installed texlive and the example compiles so it was something on my end or with miktex

Comment: I reinstalled miktex 2.9 full and got the problem at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309140/after-miktex-update-when-using-lualatex-package-pgf-error-driver-file-pgfsys and after solving that the code compiles fine. So it was something on my end or perhaps miktex.

Answer (score 3):

This compiles fine (note what is commented out here: the `\batchmode` commands; the `silence` package, and the line with the `luatex` pacakge).

```
%\tracingall
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
%\batchmode

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{silence}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=1in,a4paper]{geometry} % a5paper for electronic reading
%\usepackage{luatex, graphicx}
\usepackage[space]{grffile}
\usepackage{tikz, pgffor}
\usepackage{pdfcolmk}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{flafter}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{movie15}
\usepackage{xfrac}


%\scrollmode
%\batchmode
\begin{document}
%\scrollmode%\chapendfootnote

asdf % <-- add some content

%\batchmode
\end{document}
```

**Remarks**

- Do not use `\batchmode` if you don't know what it's for; and if you do know what it's for, you know that you should not use it when trying to find an error. Same for `\scrollmode`.
- Aguably, the `silence` package should not be used when trying to locate an error either. (However, it is probably fine in most cases to leave it in.)
- The package `luatex.sty` cannot be used with the `pdfTeX` engine, but other packages, such as `fontenc` indicate that you intend to use `pdfTeX`.
- If you give a 100+ files, you are probably not providing a [minimal example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528), which is often required for others to provide a meaningful solution. (This is not about 'attitude', but general point about what is usually the best and quickest way to get a useful and/or meaningful solution.)

  - Thus, if the file provided in the question is **not** meaningfully related to the 'real' problem with the 'real' file, there is no guarantee that solving the problems with the file given in the question will also solve the 'real' problem.

**Edit**

If you are using LuaTeX as the engine, for this example at least, you need to either **not** load `movie15.sty` (which is obsolete anyway) or load `luatex85.sty`, which helps deal with the major changes introduced in versions of LuaTeX > 0.80.  But, as a general rule, you should also not load `fontenc`.

Comment: You seem to fail to realize that the above code doesn't work on my system. Just because it works on yours does absolutely no good.  I use lualatex as I said before. I also said all the code worked fine before I had to reinstall. So it is not my code, per se. You seem to be unfamiliar with programming and how dependencies and such and simply play the imitation game(on tex.stackexchange it is the MWE). In fact I have given a nearly MWE and MNWE... which is optimal. Sure, my real code might have issues but if the above cannot compile then my code can never compile. Do you not realize that?

Comment: I included all those packages BECAUSE they might have some interdependecies that's causing the problem. Again, whatever I am doing on top of the above code is irrelevant so please get it out of your head that more code is required. If lualatex cannot compile the above fine then it is not something I have done(as far as going is concerned). No amount of adding more complexity on top of the above code will solve the problem, no matter how much you want to believe it.

Comment: If the above compiles for you then it is a configuration problem on my end or you are using outside software that I used when it was working, that simple. If you truly want to help you would actually think about what is going on and report what versions of software you are using rather than asking for something that only gets further away from helping.

Comment: As I said, I am using miktex light 2.9. I have all the packages installed that I am using as far as I know(miktex will install packages on the fly that are missing). What latex configuration and version are you using?

Comment: I am not making *ad hominem* statements about your knowledge (or lack of knowledge about programming or TeX or anything; please do the same.) But, to reiterate: I am **not** asking for more code. I don't know how else to say that. If you are using LuaTeX, you need to say that up front. If you are using LuaTeX, then don't use `fontenc`. A MWE involves *testing* whether the same error appears when a package is loaded or not; that is your job when you build an MWE, not everyone else's. It is a trivial but time-consuming thing to do if you have loaded lots of packages.

Comment: Try loading `\usepackage{luatex85}` (or not loading the obsolete package `movie15`). (The reason I say don't use `fontenc` is both because you shouldn't generally be loading it with either XeTeX or LuaTeX and because it is highly misleading about what engine you are in fact using.)